# zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: too many length or distance symbols

Tags: python, hex, compression, zlib, decompiling

Encountering this error for decompressing chunks of a file.

I already decompressed successfully about 5 chunks of data.
But there is just one range of data that doens't get decompressed.
The header should be right.

Header 78 9C

This is only a chunk of the whole file. The file itself consists of multiple compressed chunks.

```
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
```

My IDLE history:

```
file.seek(0) 
data = file.read()

decomp = zlib.decompress(data)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#123>", line 1, in <module>
    t1 = zlib.decompress(data)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: too many length or distance symbols
```

The outcome should look like this:

```
0:100:76:mot/pc/sk_c001_lt/lsdpack.bin
```

I searched already for this and found out that there is a newer version of zlib that maybe should fix that. (Now 1.12.12) (New 1.12.13)

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a valid zlib header, but the deflate data that follows has an error in the first two bytes. Your data was corrupted somehow.

Comment: Youre right. Did download the file again and it worked now. Idk how the file even got modified in the first place. Modified date's saying that nothings changed.